# What is the size of the ammonium ion?

Tags: ions

I did an experiment in which I dissolved certain substances in water, measured the conductivity and compared that with the ion-radius. One of the things I dissolved was $\ce{NH4Cl}$. What should I use as the ion-radius  for $\ce{NH4}$, since it is not really one atom?

Comment: I finally found it :D It is 148 m^-12